# Get route name by current route ABP framework

Tags: angular-ui-router, abp

I'm working on ABP framework with Angular UI

I have a `route.provider.ts` class that uses ABP [router service](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Modifying-the-Menu), so I have something like:

```
export const APP_ROUTE_PROVIDER=[ {
  provide APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: configureRoutes,
    deps: [RoutesService],
    multi: true
}

] function configureRoutes(routesService: RoutesService) {
  return (): void=> {
    routesService.add([ {
        path: '/visits',
        name: '::Menu:Visit'
        ....
      }

      ])
  }
}
```

Then I use this in the `app.module.ts` as :

providers: [ APP_ROUTE_PROVIDER]

So, everything works well, but now I have created a new service where I have the current route as:

```
const url = this.router.url;
```

I want to know how to retrieve the name property from ABP RoutesService with the current URL. I.E

How can I achieve this if `const url = '/visits'` I want to retrieve `'::Menu:Visit'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Abp RoutesService find() to find the route item and then access its property.

```
var rt = this.routesService.find( i => i.path ==='/admin/users/add');
console.log(rt.name);
```